# JSONArray in response cannot be converted

Tags: java, android

I am getting a JSONObject in response from an API

```
{
"contact": null,
"error": false,
"msg": "get Contacts successfully",
"synccontactstimestamp": "2018-02-07 11:34:40.0",
"contactjson": "[{\"contactName\":\"4B9B4474C091D55A981ADBB7893FB4E1\",\"contactNumber\":\"0F8F3E9514D329F32CE7B03B9D276D72\"}, {\"contactName\":\"12E09C05C0E456AC2398BDA841986609\",\"contactNumber\":\"035774DB94BFE24BDEDA0B4B45F1372A0CC8EE72A457C3AAA35F79627FD13728\"}, {\"contactName\":\"9344BBF08ACACC4C85A9B83C55BA93C0\",\"contactNumber\":\"E1633601A6632356DB2F08058CA42504\"}, {\"contactName\":\"CCF51D9C27123ACD19F163F6C2BCCD28\",\"contactNumber\":\"89DD6C0E185D1067AC45CEE12DFA6A07\"}, {\"contactName\":\"A8309A8EC81E4DF50306FE4651D63F53\",\"contactNumber\":\"E8781EE87E9036B794BE44D7411FBFCF\"}
```

I am trying to get this JSONArray with key "contactjson" but it gives an exception 
`Value of string type cannot be converted to JSONArray.`

Any idea how to fetch this?

Comment: If you look carefully, you will see that the contactjson is actually a string. The data wasn't sent correct.

Comment: Your array element contain quotes this is problem.

Comment: Your problem is that is NOT a JSON array in the data - it is a string because of the quotes. You could grab the string and reparse it as json and it would work but the sending service is breaking the JSON atm

Comment: @VishvaDave it is valid

Comment: pls check my answer below Neemani

Comment: yeah , response is valid , only thing is  contactjson key is coming as String, we can convert it to JSONArray.

Answer (score 1):

as you see value of **contactjson** key is coming as **String**,

First take your contactjson into a String variable like

```
 String data = yourResponse.contactjson;
```

then convert into JSONArray

```
 JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(data);
```

Comment: Is this going to work ?

Comment: yes it will convert the string to a JSONArray.

Comment: The data is malformed itself . it need to be in proper formate. No need to create `JSONArray` from string when you can directly access it .

Comment: if you see value of contactjson key is coming as String, and then its throwing error Value of string type cannot be converted to JSONArray.  

we can convert it on our end what is wrong with this

Comment: here question is not about should i change my data from the server , as User is getting in the app String as response , why can not we convert it and use :)

Comment: thanks @Thunder..its working. You saved my day

Comment: your welcome , please accept my answer Neemani